# Any DB2 database project support for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, db2, db2-connect

Back at Tech Ed in 2008, Microsoft announced that:

> IBM and Microsoft have agreed to work together to integrate IBM DB2 database access with Visual Studio Team System Database Edition.
>   -- [Microsoft Press Release - 6/3/2008](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2008/jun08/06-03TechEdDevPR.mspx)

Has anyone seen evidence that this has actually happened? More importantly, has anyone had success moving DB2 projects to VS 2010?

We have some DB2 database projects that rely on the IBM Database Add-ins for Visual Studio 2008. I have been unable to find any mention of 2010 Add-Ins on IBM's site and they only support the add-ins through forums. I asked about VS 2010 support on the forums and got no response.

Comment: Based on the info that I've received thus far, Microsoft has completed their work to support other (non SQL Server) databases in the Database Development Tools, but IBM has yet to deliver anything on their end. I still have some inquiries in at IBM. Maybe someone there will give some info.

Comment: Well, as the other .net developer working with db2, I shall keep an eye on this thread in case some progress is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the beta for VS 2010/.net 4.0 support is finally out. I'll follow up after we've done some testing.

[DB2 VS 2010 add-in (Beta)](http://www.db2teamblog.com/2010/09/open-beta-for-visual-studio-2010.html) (**NOTE:** Original link is dead. See [archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120330081933/http://www.db2teamblog.com/2010/09/open-beta-for-visual-studio-2010.html).)

Comment: Any news?  I have a client that uses a DB2 database for one of their main systems and they want me to consider doing systems integration work between it and other systems that use SQL Server.  I've never worked with DB2 before.